# How do I document "trigger_error()" for a class method?

Tags: php, error-handling, documentation

If I have the following class method:

```
class ClassA
{
    public function MethodA()
    {
        trigger_error('An error has occurred.', E_USER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

... then what is the accepted way of documenting that it might "throw" (issue) an error using `trigger_error()` explicitly? The closest I found was to use either `@throws`, or `@exception`. Is it possible this behavior should not be documented at all, or instead included in the method description itself?

The reason I ask this question about `trigger_error` is because I use a custom error logging class which is called by a **custom error handler**, hence it is convenient to issue runtime errors and output/save them in an organized fashion. Should I just use `@see trigger_error` or `@see ErrorLog` (my custom class) instead?

---

**EDIT:**

For those wondering about the script flow if an error is triggered: the script will *not* terminate execution on `E_USER_ERROR`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The script will not terminate execution on E_USER_ERROR.

This may be your bigger issue. PHP's error mechanism is rather... primitive. It basically only knows two modes: notify the developer of *potential* issues by triggering a notice, warning or stern warning (a.k.a. error), or to stop the script by triggering a fatal error. Triggering a (fatal) error yet continuing with the script execution is not really its purpose.

The function should simply be documented informally with "triggers error if X, Y or Z". This *typically* means "will kill script if X, Y or Z". If you're overriding that behaviour, that's up to you.

Formally documented errors make sense if those errors can be handled in a standardised manner, which is very much what exceptions are. They have formal documentation standards (`@throws`) and can be handled in flexible ways (`try..catch`). You really *should* use exceptions for the purpose you're trying to use errors here.

Comment: _"PHP's error mechanism is rather... primitive"_ - I rethought and reworked the code-parts in question. Exception handling _did_ prove more useful and versatile than `trigger_error`.